# simple xml won't work

Tags: javascript, xml

Here's my xml file (simple.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <firstLevelChild>first level child 1</firstLevelChild>
    <firstLevelChild>first level child 2</firstLevelChild>
</root>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
<p><button onclick="doSomethingSimple()">do something simple</button></p>
<p id="demo">demo</p>

<script>
function doSomethingSimple(){
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            simpleFunction(xhttp);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "simple.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function simpleFunction(xml){
    var xmldoc = xml.responseXML;
    var rootNode, firstChildOfRoot, textNode;
    var outputText;

    rootNode = xmldoc.documentElement;
    firstChildOfRoot = rootNode.firstChild;
    textNode = firstChildOfRoot.firstChild;
    outputText = textNode.nodeValue;
    //outputText = "hallo from 'simpleFunction()'";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = outputText;
}
</script>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. Can't figure out why not.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? Add console.log or debugger statements, which bits of your function execute? Do the variables have the values you expect?

Comment: There is a debugger statement: outputText = "hallo from 'simpleFunction()'". That works fine when I un-comment it. But only if I comment-out the previous outputText = ... statement.

Comment: @rippon, quentin is talking about JavaScript's special [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) keyword

Comment: @Quill, Okay, thanks. I'll go away and learn about that. I take it, then, that you can't see anything obviously wrong with my code - correct?

Comment: @rippon, I don't know much about XML, sorry :(